# Как перенаправить пользователя на определенную страницу если action занято?

Tags: java, servlet

У меня форма:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="addition">

        <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить">

    </form>
</body>
```

И метод в сервлете:

```
...
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //тут что-то делает
}
...
```

И после того как он что-то сделает мне надо перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу, но проблема что атрибут `action="addition"` уже занят соединением с сервлетом... Как мне сделать перенаправление?

Comment: Не понятно как Вы увязали перенаправление с атрибутом action=addition. Что с ним не так? А перенаправление выплняется так resp.sendRedirect("url на который перенаправить");

Comment: вам, очевидно, нужен ответ 301/302 и соответствующий заголовок location